# How to use intersect in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables. I want to check the very last data inserted in the tables.
So, I want to retrieve the last data from both tables and then check if that last data from both tables are same or not.

```
$q1 =   "SELECT * ".
        "FROM `admin`, `student` ".
        "ORDER BY `admin`.`id` DESC  LIMIT 1 ".
        "INTERSECT".
        "SELECT *".
        "FROM `admin`, `student`".
        "WHERE `admin`.`pcode` = `student`.`code` AND
`admin`.`puser_name` = `student`.`puser_name`";
```

I cannot use intersect operator so I am getting difficulty in changing in other form.

Comment: You forgot the space after `INTERSECT`, so your query reads like `INTERSECTSELECT`.

Comment: I edited that, but the main problem is how to change my query in another form. I mean I cannot use INTERSECT,right?

Comment: $q1 =   "SELECT * ".
            "FROM admin, student ".
            "WHERE admin.pcode = student.code AND admin.puser_name = student.puser_name AND admin.pcode IN ".
            "(SELECT admin.pcode ".
            "FROM admin ".
            "ORDER BY admin.id DESC  LIMIT 1) "
            ;

Comment: In addition to the space problem noted by KIKO Software, `INTERSECT` is not supported by MySQL at all. So I marked this question as a duplicate of another asking for an alternative way to achieve the result.

Comment: When I put LIMIT  inside IN, it creates an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM admin
WHERE admin.pcode = student.code
INTERSECT
SELECT *FROM student
WHERE admin.puser_name = student.puser_name
ORDER BY admin.id DESC  LIMIT 1";
```

The INTERSECT operator compares the result of two queries and returns the distinct rows that are output by both left and right queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$q1 =   "SELECT * FROM admin, student ORDER BY admin.id DESC  LIMIT 1 
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT * FROM admin, student 
        WHERE admin.pcode = student.code AND admin.puser_name = student.puser_name 
        ";
```

Hope will help